# Should a Vote to Delete Require a Comment

Tags: discussion

An answer of mine received one vote to delete (["If" statement inside of Asymptote function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245815/if-statement-inside-of-asymptote-function/245821#245821)), but I think it is a good answer and it was accepted by the OP.  I would maybe learn something if I knew why I got that deletion vote.  Is there, or should there be, a way to see who voted to delete?  Should a comment be required with a delete vote so that the poster can learn from it?

Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry for the delete vote, but I thought that your solution should have been improved. I omitted a comment, since there was already a comment in which you were asked about improvement, if I remember correctly. The vote was before it was accepted, of course. I learned from this ugly discussion (see below) that I should leave a comment in future for not-so-apparent-delete votes

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks for the explanation.  No need to apologize because it didn't bother me.  I love this site and just wanted to know how I could improve my answers and conform to the community standards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The system auto-flags the answers if there is very little text but a lot of markup content (in your case code blocks) and it gets slightly more paranoid if the rep score of the user is not-that-high.

It should usually be ignored in the cases like your answer, however, because our reviewers stopped reading questions and answers and started to vote randomly, you get stuff like that. Sometimes people genuinely voted for deletion because they don't have enough coffee. So it's a mess.

I have also examples of people voting *Looks OK* to spam more than once. And yes we can see who voted.

So I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Agreed. Some reviewers may be badge-hunters...

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  I'll try to include more normal text with my code next time.

Comment: @Werner: Don't forget the guys here who stopped reviewing right at the point of having the silver or gold badge ;-) And we've guys here that automatically grab the review and get a daily count of 10+ review on some of the queues

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I hope you realize that one of the votes is yours together with usual names.

Comment: @percusse: Yes, I know... And I still live with it. I found the solution too short. Perhaps I had to write a comment why I voted for deletion

Comment: Or maybe you should realize that solutions must stay unless it is against any policy of abuse, spam etc. Wrong answers are still answers. It is not to your liking whether they should stay or not. There are two meta questions about wrong answers and the conclusion is they stay. In this case it is not only correct but the accepted one.

Comment: @percusse: Our views differ as usual. I can live with that.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It is not a point of view unfortunately this time. It is just reviewing without realizing that these users might actually need information.  Instead just blindly clicking buttons to get stupid dots and other bullshit. Aren't you the one who went berserk and changed your nickname and decided to leave because of a downvote very recently? Maybe you can relate to people whose answers are deleted because of you. You don't even feel bad about it when it is not about your rep and badges and this and that.

Comment: @percusse: I was and am the one who was disappointed about the downvote of an answer because the OP just stole my answer and when I notified him that this is not really ok, he downvoted me. That was my rant... Deleting does not cost rep. And if I would be rep/badge hunter, I would not answer questions on counters/macros/ToC etc. Those questions does not give rep and badge.  And I am **not** the one who says `Looks Ok` when it is spam etc. You can readily notify one of the mods to get a review ban for me, if that guarantees your happiness

Comment: @percusse: Final comment: I am completely not satisfied with your answer here, but I did not downvote it (other's would have done/will do so, perhaps), because I am still too polite perhaps, for this site